# Difference between CoreData sqllite file size with images stored in it and total iCloud space

Tags: objective-c, core-data, icloud

I have decided to give a try to saving images into CoreData as binary.
They are just small images from 2k to 90k maximum, and I can say I have trashed many lines of code, especially the ones dealing with iCloud issues.

Considering that CoreData is the only storage I put in iCloud using properties such as NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey, I have noticed that my sqlite file is actually about 1.6mb in size. While the total iCloud space occupied by the application itself, as seen in the iOS settings, is nearly 34mb, and I do not have any other documents around.

I already put the NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption as option, so I am wondering what is causing all this space to be taken. Probably the transaction log ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using External Data References.

With each change to the entity that stores your images you are writing out all of the image data. With external data references, the image data would be stored as a separate file, and can be deleted once it is no longer referenced.